# Are All Minecraft Bedrock Editions the Same?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

A while ago, many platforms of Minecraft merged into one version called Minecraft Bedrock Edition. They are supposed to have the same features, but *do they?*

Comment: Related: [Tagging for Minecraft Bedrock Edition (duplicate)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12856/93118) and [The great Minecraft tag family cleanup!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14846/93118)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## For The Most Part

All versions of Minecraft are for the most part the same with some exclusives.

(Note: This list ignores the whole Render Dragon thing going on because it's changing right now and not especially worth noting for this question.)

#### Every Version...

- All editions have a slightly different world generation than another.
  This often goes unnoticed but still exists.

#### Windows 10 Exclusive

- Windows 10 is the only Bedrock platform that supports the Bedrock
  JavaScript API.
- Windows 10 is currently the only platform that supports raytracing.

#### iOS "Exclusives"

- `.mcworld`s, `.mcpack`s, and `.mcaddon`s got changed a bit ago in an iOS update where you can't directly run them without a share method (i.e. a special map/addon app, not Safari/Files Viewer).
- Thought I might include this: iOS often has more patches than the other versions, which causes them to run on a higher patch while still being cross-play compatible.

#### Console Exclusives (Playstation 4/5 / Xbox One / Nintendo Switch)

- None of the console editions of Bedrock allow you to connect to just any Bedrock Servers, only allowing access to “Featured” servers. For example, you cannot play BrokenLens on a PS4 but you can play The Hive.

#### PlayStation 4 Exclusives

- PlayStation 4 can use a PlayStation Network account to play with other PlayStation users, but to play cross-play one must sign into Xbox Live.
- PlayStation 4 has the option to go into the PlayStation 4 Edition before it joined Bedrock Edition, which is the same as Legacy Console but updated to Village & Pillage. This is great if you miss the old minigames on legacy console, like Glide (Elytra Course), Battle (Survival Games), and Tumble (Spleef). Sadly now that Bedrock exists there are few people playing legacy PS4 Minecraft minigames to play with.

## Are these Major?

**No, with the exception of the Legacy PS4 Option.**

- World generation is so slightly different and is rarely different in the first place.
- The JavaScript API is rarely used because it is extremely limited and commands are more fun to use anyway.
- Raytracing is supported by graphics cards that most people don't have, so most Windows 10 users can't use raytracing.
- The iOS files not working without sharing is annoying, but not too big of a deal since most iOS users use apps to get packs and worlds anyway.
- iOS patch thing doesn’t affect gameplay at all.
- The featured servers are the most commonly played servers for Bedrock, with very few getting a player count even close to the featured ones.
- All the PlayStation/Xbox Live account situation does is force PS4
  Minecraft users to make an Xbox account for cross-play and
  server-play.
- The legacy PS4 option though is probably better to remain a PS4
  exclusive, since it is mainly for nostalgic and minigame purposes.
  Also, if everyone could play PS4 minigames it would just turn into
  the PC players destroying console and pocket players again.
  *Not
  to mention that there would probably be legal issues porting 4J's
  game to all platforms (I'm no legal expert and not pretending to be one), and not a task the Bedrock team would want
  anyway, this was likely an option after Xbox users refused to update
  to Bedrock. They likely wanted to reduce community backlash as well.*

#### If I left something out please comment/edit.

Comment: Under console restrictions I put "Xbox/Playstation/Nintendo" as the feature removal is very likely to be present in the ports to the upcoming next generation of game console hardware. The restriction necessitating the removal are not technical but are likely to do with content control.

Comment: @520 I think we should keep it to PS4, Xbox One, ... as to not confuse people into thinking that Xbox 360 and PS3 apply, once Minecraft has been released for new consoles we can add Playstation 4/5 as an edit, but we should probably keep it specific as to not confuse with non-Bedrock versions of the game.

Comment: but this is why I started with "None of the console editions of **Bedrock**.." PS3 and 360 never had a Bedrock edition, so of course the changes aren't going to apply to them. Because of this the question isn't really relevant to PS3/360 anyway.

Comment: @520 I feel its best to keep the clarity anyway, because even when it becomes outdated people always edit and update things on this site